# How to create a living character that no longer needs food?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation, food-and-drink

I want to replicate a character I made in a different campaign. I want my character to not be a construct or undead. The only mechanic I truly need for this character is the ability to fast endlessly without penalty. I would prefer to be a divine caster, but that's less important.

http://www.middlefingerofvecna.com/search/label/Cleric?m=1
Was what I used in the other campaign.

Comment: are you interested in the mechanical advantages of not need to eat ( i.e. not needing to buy food ) or do you just want the character being perceived not eating?

Comment: Answer in answers, not comments.   Comment-answers have been removed..

Comment: I was looking more for a flavor of character. The perceived not eating is also valid

Answer (score 11):

An Oracle with the Solar mystery could accomplish that.
One of the mystery revelations is:

> **Serpent in the Sun (Su)**
>
>   So long as you are exposed to at least 4 hours of sunlight per day, **you no longer need to eat to survive** and you gain +2 bonus on saves against diseases.
>   At 5th level, you become immune to non-magical diseases and no longer need to drink water to survive. At 10th level, you become immune to magical diseases, gain a +2 bonus on saving throws against poisons, and only need to sleep half as long to rest or recover from fatigue or exhaustion.
>   At 15th level, you become immune to poison and fatigue.
>   You lose these benefits if you fail to spend at least 4 hours in sunlight in a 24-hour period.

Taken from http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/oracle/mysteries/paizo---oracle-mysteries/solar-mystery

Answer (score 7):

Many ways, more or less easy to reach.

The easiest is to get the right magical items:

- [Ring of Sustenance](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/ring-of-sustenance): for 2500gp it "continually provides its wearer with life-sustaining nourishment" (up to the GM to decide if it means food appears magically in your mouth or if you can fast as long as you want)
- [Clear Spindle Ioun Stone](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/ioun-stones/clear-spindle-ioun-stone): for 4000gp it "sustains the wearer without food or water".

Then there are the class features:

- Strangely enough, the Monk doesn't have any of this. But the Unchained one can get Ki Metabolism, which makes you able among other stuff to eat and drink only 1/4 as often as normal and to put yourself in suspended animation without a limit of time.
- Any caster able to cast [Create Demiplane, Greater](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/create-demiplane) (Cleric, Oracle, Sorcerer, Wizard, Witch 9 or anyone with the solitude subdomain) can create a plane with the timeless trait:

> On planes with this trait, time still passes, but the effects of time are diminished. How the timeless trait affects certain activities or conditions such as hunger, thirst, aging, the effects of poison, and healing varies from plane to plane. The danger of a timeless plane is that once an individual leaves such a plane for one where time flows normally, conditions such as hunger and aging occur retroactively. (...).

I may have forgotten some options, but these are valid !

Answer (score 5):

The following Psionic classes will give you access to the [Sustenance](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/psionic-powers/s/sustenance) Power at the listed class levels.

- At class level 3 a Psion, Tactician, or Vitalist.
- At class level 4 a Cryptic, Dread, Psychic Warrior, or Wilder.
- At class level 5 a Marksman.

> **Description:** You can go without food and water for one day. Each time you manifest this power, your body manufactures sufficient solid and liquid nourishment to satisfy your needs for that time.

So if you can live with a bit of multiclassing and be both cleric and one of the above classes you can spend 3 power points per day to not require food or drink.

As KRyan mentions in the comments, if race is open for consideration for your character build then for even less cost you can choose to be an [Elan](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/races/elan/). Elan have the racial trait "Repletion" which will do the job.

> **Repletion (Su):** An elan can sustain his body without need of food or water. If he spends 1 power point, an elan does not need to eat or drink for 24 hours.

Comment: If mentioning psionics, the elan race seems important to note here.

Answer (score 3):

Applying the [Fungal Creature template](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/fungal-creature) to your character would remove your ability to eat or sleep, at the cost of +1 CR, and also dying and being reborn as a mushroom creature.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are more interested in the fluff behind not eating you could simply "reskin" your character needs.

For example, you said you want your character to be a divine caster, then you could reskin your meal as a prayer to your god.
Doing the prayer take you some time and need a collection of incenses, which you light while praying. Of course the incenses cost you 5sp a day, which coincidentally ( not really ) is the cost of a trail ration.
And in city, where your friends pay less for food, you may be able to find the same substances which are used for your incenses but fresh. You can't preserve them in this state but are less pricey.

Of course meet with your GM, explain your idea and work together on the details.